# Normal or tension force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I read that a rope applies a force equal to its tension wherever it touches (pulls)

Suppose a rope is connected to a block then why do we ignore the normal force by the rope ? Or its the tension force in disguiuse ?

Does a rope apply both Tension and normal ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the tension force in disguise. The block has its weight acting downwards. This is counteracted by the tension in the rope. Since this force works in the opposite direction, you can call this the normal force in disguise. If the force is not balanced, the block would move upwards or downwards.

Comment: so basically the normal is the tension or the tension is the normal.
or is it that both are different things and rope exerts both ????

Comment: It is the same thing. Remember, the normal force may exist in different forms. In this case, it is the tension. In the case of fluids, it is the buoyancy that is the normal force.  In case of a block kept on a table, it is the force exerted by the table on the block.

Comment: can you please provide any sort of reference o this statement like a book or article........

Comment: Well, I'd personally ask you to go over google are type stuff like, " Is buoyancy a normal force? Or is tension a normal force? That way, if you search yourself, you'll slowly get more comfortable with the topic. I'll search for some material meanwhile. I'll send you, if I find any.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay IMHO you are wrong

Answer (score 0):

acoording to newtons third law every action has equal and opposite reaction.

Normal force is an example of a reaction force.

Tension is just a pulling force that a rope gives to the object it is attached to.

It has nothing to do with normal force.

the force with which the block pulls the force back can be called normal which even though will have magnitude of tension as per newtons third law they are different.

in fact we can call them to be a action reaction pair.

Answer (score 0):

Tension force and normal force are two different kind of forces. The common thing between them is that they both are contact electromagnetic force.

The uncommon thing between two things is that normal force is pushing in nature , while tension force can be pulling as well as pushing. However in case of strings it always pull.

We don't show normal force as the string doesnt apply normal force since it is treated to be massless.

Comment: so mass less things do not apply normal force.